# Can anyone kill a Watcher?

Tags: marvel

Watchers are immortal and allegedly the oldest race in the universe. One of the Watchers, Uatu, lived on Earth's moon and watched the human race. Their powers are nearly infinite as they can alter molecular composition, teleport anywhere in the universe instantly and also to other dimensions, use telepathy and telekinesis, augment any abilities, manipulate time and space, and use energy projection as a weapon. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watcher_(comics)))

So can they be killed?

(Note: Uatu was no longer a Watcher after FF#400, being punished by the High Tribunal. He Who Summons exiled Uatu to Earth.)

Comment: Using the Infinity Gauntlet? Almost certainly

Comment: "*With all six Stones, I can simply snap my fingers, they would all cease to exist. I call that mercy.*" Did Thanos kill anyone or erase their existence? Uatu could do that as well.

Comment: Pftt, in one story there was "dead body" of Living Tribunal! Only thing one can wonder is what does it mean "to kill" entities like that. Using Infinity Gauntlet one could retroactively make all Watchers to never exist at all.

Answer (score 2):

Watchers are nigh invulnerable to everything in the known universe. Uatu himself batted his cousin Aron the rogue Watcher to spare the Earth's solar system from destruction. As the two immortals battled "a brutal and most savage war is concurrently waged across the infinite rivers of reality." *(Fantastic Four #400:* Even The Watchers Can Die *)*

Neither watcher died in the encounter, however Aron weakened faster than Uatu giving Uatu the upper hand. Uatu commented that:

> It would be so easy to **destroy** you now...to simply **erase** you from existence!

Instead Uatu turned Aron into a being of living energy. However, if "erasing from existence" is the same as killing, then a Watcher could "kill" another Watcher. I would argue that this is not the same thing as killing, however.

As such the only known instance of a Watcher being killed is also found in Fantastic Four #400 when the Celestial Exiter killed The One using energy stored up over a period of centuries to accomplish this one feat.

[image: The Death of The One]

It is important to note that while Exiter did kill a Watcher, he only did so after beam of celestial energy swept over The One rendering him unconscious.  If The One were able to fight back, we do not know if Exiter could have killed The One so easily.

Uatu was eventually killed by Nick Fury in *Original Sin* with a single bullet to the head, however at that time he was not a Watcher. After interfering with Aron's plans he was cast out by the High Tribunal and was no longer a member of the Watcher race. On Earth Uatu was called "Uatu the Watcher" out of respect, but he did not have their powers.

[image: Uatu is not a Watcher]

Answer (score 1):

## In short, yes

In Issue#1 of [Original Sins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Sin_(comics)#cite_note-1), Uatu, the Watcher is murdered by a clean shot through his head. He was shot twice and his eyes were stolen (image below).

[image]
 <sub>*Original Sins Issue#1: Who shot the Watcher?*</sub>

Although it isn't mentioned who all are capable of doing such a heinous crime, Nick Fury does say that there are quite a few people who could possibly kill Uatu.

[image]
 <sub>*Original Sins Issue#1: Who shot the Watcher?*</sub>

However, it is later in Issue#8 revealed that:

> Fury himself confesses killing Uatu and stealing his eye.

Comment: Uatu was not a watcher. The High Council cast him out of the race in FF#400. Nick Fury definitely could not have killed a Watcher with a bullet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they can and have been.

[Original Sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_Sin_(comics)):

> "Original Sin" is a 2014 comic book storyline published by Marvel Comics. **The story features Nick Fury and the Avengers investigating the murder of Uatu the Watcher**, only to suffer trauma from what they see in his eyes.

(emphasis added)

Comment: Worth reading if one is interested in the Watchers.

Comment: Interesting but Uatu was not a Watcher. High Council cast him out of the race in FF#400. They call him Watcher by name only

Comment: @Raj - He was not "stripped of his title," he was no longer even a member of the Watcher race. He became mortal and lost all benefits of being a Watcher. I own the book. The exact words from the High Tribunal were, "You are a Watcher no more! You are hereby banished from your race." He did have some powers remaining because he teleported himself and FF back to Earth. When do you believe the High Tribunal re-instated him? And if they did, why was he hiding on Earth (instead of "watching" from his citadel)?

Comment: Is that the same [Marvel.com article that doesn't say he was murdered](https://www.marvel.com/characters/uatu-the-watcher) by Nick Fury (and hence the "Fury killed a Watcher" argument is moot?)

Comment: @VogonPoet While I cannot point to any particular issue that says Uatu's status changed, you are relying on one nearly 25-year-old issue to rebut several posts and I think you may be putting too much faith in the immutability of comic book continuity. I have little doubt that Uatu has, in the time since *Fantastic Four* v1 400 was published, regained his status as a full-on Watcher.

Comment: @VogonPoet Marvel's site also doesn't include any info on Uatu after the original Civil War storyline, which was 13 years ago. I wouldn't think it's a good idea to use what that site says or doesn't say to support your argument.

Comment: @PatrickWynne - You are asking me to exclude Marvel.com from canon? After you yourself used it... ? Can you pick the canon/non-canon bits out for us all (without speculating please)?

Comment: @VogonPoet I didn't use it. And all I'm saying is that you can't use the exclusion of a 2014 storyline from that site as evidence when none of the info goes past 2006. Apart from that, though, the comics are canon, not the website. I mean, there's this disclaimer from "Marvel Editorial Staff" right there on the very page itself: "Take note, True Believer! This crowd-sourced content has not yet been verified for accuracy by our erudite editors!" That article also says that Uatu was "[e]ventually reinstated into the Watchers", so using it to prove he's not a Watcher anymore is iffy to begin with

Answer (score 0):

This One-Above-All certainly.

The One-Above-All is Omnipotent (all powerful), Omniscient (all knowing), and Omnipresent (everywhere). He is the most powerful being in the Marvel Multiverse. He exists beyond space and time. His power is unlimited, incalculable and immeasurable, he cannot be damaged in any way and he has control over all forms of energy.

[image: This One-Above-All]

There are others too, a simple Google search, for marvel cosmic entities would suffice.

Comment: You stuck a picture of the Living Tribunal in there - One Above All is his boss :)